# :APP_USER usage in SQL query. Oracle Application Express (Apex) 5.0.4

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to use session variable `:APP_USER` in query in selection database statement like this:

```
select * from :APP_USER.data
```

I have users `john.doe` and `johny.b`. 
I have table `john.doe.data` and i want to get all data from this table. Also i have table `johny.b.data` and when `johny.b` will login in, I want to get data from table `johny.b.data`.

I hope you understand my plan, so it is like every user have own data table and I want to display table according to logged in user. What will be the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't have enough rank but this tag should be oracle-apex not apex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this would be possible but shouldn't be done. You'd be better off doing select * from apex_user.table (prefix not needed) where column = :APP_USER and having them all in one big table or having a different table (but same apex_schema) per user. How you'd go about creating this table is up to you - you could select a pseudo-table from dual and then only create it when necessary to prefent any table not found issues.

You'll no doubt run into tablespace permission issues down the line or worse - give the apex user more security permissions than it requires if you go down your intended route which will make exporting and importing a nightmare.

Comment: OK, i understand.